# How to convert darknet weights into CoreML model without loosing accuracy?

Tags: python, keras, yolo, coreml, darknet

I have trained a YOLOv3-SPP model and I am trying to convert it to CoreML so I can use it inside of my app. However, I cannot seem to find a way to do it without losing a significant amount of accuracy. I have tried converted the .weights file into a Keras .h5 file and then turning that into a CoreML model but when testing the h5 model it seems to not be able to detect anything in some pictures where the darknet weights worked perfectly. Also in pictures where the Keras model detects an object, (in many cases) the bounding box is either way to big or way to small. I assume this means that my CoreML model was about as accurate as the h5 model (and therefore not useable in my case). I need to detect relatively small objects from a distance so I need to use the YOLOv3-SPP since it is more accurate than the YOLOv3 and the YOLOv3-Tiny models. I don't need that much speed. I also just tried training a CoreML model using the same data with Turi Create (batch size was 8 and 50,000 iterations) however it does not seem to work very well either (for comparison I trained the darknet model with batch size 64 for 3,000 iterations on Google Colab). How can I convert my darknet weights into CoreML without loosing as little accuracy as possible? Is there something I am missing? I am pretty new to Machine Learning and all of the concepts so writing my own script is basically impossible. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You probably missed something. ;-) This shouldn't happen. My guess is that the preprocessing on the Core ML model is wrong. This happens so often that I wrote a blog post about: https://machinethink.net/blog/help-core-ml-gives-wrong-output/

Comment: I haven't tested the CoreML model yet. My problem is not that my CoreML model gives me wrong predictions but that the Keras .h5 model that I have lost a lot of accuracy during the conversion process. I am trying to find out how to convert my darknet weights to CoreML without loosing accuracy. BTW, do you know any Github project that I can put my CoreML model in to test it?

Comment: There is always my repo at: https://github.com/hollance/YOLO-CoreML-MPSNNGraph :-)